# XSLT 2.0: Item type error when passing position as template parameter

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've been struggling to simplify code as much as possible. Due to the nature of the XML I can't share the raw and I've had to sanitize the code down to just the snippet that is causing me a headache. Instead of creating a discrete line for each month I want to just call the same code 12 times. This saves space (in 20k+ lines I need all the space I can use) and it also simplifies things when the code needs an adjustment (seems to happen quarterly lately). However, when I use the below I get the error:

> XPTY0020: Required item type of the context item for the child axis is
>   node()

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="contract">
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 12">
                <xsl:call-template name="monthPayments">
                    <xsl:with-param name="month" select="position()"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="monthPayments">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <!-- Month is the position of the for-each loop from 1 to 12 -->
        <xsl:value-of select="payments[plannedPaymentDate/@month = $month]/@amount"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've searched and found a couple of questions with this error, however the answers didn't make sense. I think the issue is around the context node having an atomic value. The solution for some seems to be declaring a context variable. However, I'm just not sure why I need that here given I'm inside a for-each which gives context to the template and the value-of in the called template. At least it does if I am not passing a position() as the parameter.

I've used the for-each x-to-y for other functions without an issue, but this is the first time I'm passing the position as the parameter of the template.

Any thoughts on how I can simplify my code snippet would be great. I just can't figure out how to get past the error!

EDIT:

The snippet was not a good example. Sorry! I need this to work under SpreadsheetML where I create a cell for each month. So it would look more like below, which obviously has a lot of preceding code for styles and the like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="contracts/ES_CMContract">
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to 12">
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s87">
                    <!-- Monthly Payments -->
                    <Data ss:Type="Number">
                        <xsl:call-template name="monthPayments">
                            <xsl:with-param name="month" select="position()"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </Data>
                </Cell>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="monthPayments">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <!-- Month is the position of the for-each loop from 1 to 12 -->
        <xsl:value-of select="payments/ES_CM2Payment[plannedPaymentDate/ESP_DATE/@month = $month]/amount/ES_COSTOBJECT/co_costprice/ESP_COSTPRICE/@anglosaxon_amount"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="for $month in 1 to 12 return contract/payments[plannedPaymentDate/@month = $month]/@amount"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or even

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="contract/payments[plannedPaymentDate/@month = (1 to 12)]/@amount"/>
</xsl:template>
```

although that might give a different order of values.

As for the need to create an XML element for each number, use

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="contracts/ES_CMContract">
        <xsl:variable name="contract" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to 12">
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s87">
                <!-- Monthly Payments -->
                <Data ss:Type="String">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$contract/payments/ES_CM2Payment[plannedPaymentDate/ESP_DATE/@month = current()]/amount/ES_COSTOBJECT/co_costprice/ESP_COSTPRICE/@anglosaxon_amount"/>
                </Data>
            </Cell>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If you really need to call a template then make sure you pass that outer variable I showed on as a second parameter.

Comment: It works perfectly in my original code snippet, but I spaced out and didn't state (or stated and deleted the paragraph) that this is embedded in SpreadsheetML where I need a cell for each month. I wish I was working in XML!!!

Comment: Great! That solved it. For my own education though. Why was the variable needed? I thought that since I was already inside the contract node I didn't need to state I was coming from that node again.

Comment: The outer `xsl:for-each select="contracts/ES_CMContract"` of course makes the current context item a `ES_CMContract` element but inside of the inner `xsl:for-each select="1 to 12"` the context items is then an integer number, an atomic value and not a node. So to have access inside of the inner for-each to the context item of the outer for-each we need a variable.